# NYC Crime Dataset

Tags: data-request, city, crime

I am looking for detailed dataset for NYC Crime similar to the one of [Chicago](https://data.cityofchicago.org/d/ijzp-q8t2).

This [dataset](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Public-Safety/Historical-New-York-City-Crime-Data/hqhv-9zeg) doesn't contain a lot of information on when/where and what kind of crimes happened at NYC.

Answer (score 3):

NYC publishes incident-level data in a similar way as Chicago (but only for felonies, it seems) at https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Public-Safety/NYPD-7-Major-Felony-Incidents/hyij-8hr7

NYC also has https://compstat.nypdonline.org/2e5c3f4b-85c1-4635-83c6-22b27fe7c75c/view/89 which while there is no "download the data" button, if you click on one of the numbers it loads points onto a map which *could* be downloaded by inspecting and understanding the AJAX request requests the browser makes to the server (not ideal by any means in terms of "open data" but it's better than nothing!)

Answer (score 2):

There is downloadable data at the map below. This will still be useful for other people and I'm sure this question will pop up in their search results.

- [NYC crime map for all crimes](https://maps.nyc.gov/crime/). Change data mapped from "all" to certain types of crime. Wait, at the bottom it says "Download" and has a link mentioned in another answer here, where you can get the data. If the map can change the crime type then the data must have the crime type in there also.